# how to use creare URL in yii1

Tags: html, ajax, yii1.x

My controller is located in following folder Controller/SiteAction/1700/Participate and my view file is located in views/site/eventview. I should impliment the button inside eventview that navigates to Controller/SiteAction/1700/Participate. And I should use

```
<a class="participate" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();ajaxAction('<?=$this->createUrl('_____/p articipate/'.$data->id)?>',$('#real-form1').serialize() + '&NonFormValue=real-form')">
```

What should i write instead of __________/p in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In Similar manner:
Yii::app()->createUrl("news/view",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))